# getting rate limit issue on aws step function map state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Hi I have a step function in which I am getting this issue after sometime :

> `Rate Exceeded. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 429; Error Code: TooManyRequestsException; Request ID: xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx; Proxy: null) on 149th index while there are total 521 index to loop through.`

I checked by setting Unreserved account concurrency to
1906 of lambda in map state. And Map state concurrency is set to 20 .

my json of state machine is :

```json
{
    "StartAt": "pre-process",
    "States": {
        "pre-process": {
            "Next": "step-1",
            "Retry": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                "Lambda.ServiceException",
                "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
            }
            ],
            "Catch": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
                ],
                "Next": "post-process"
            }
            ],
            "Type": "Task",
            "TimeoutSeconds": 86400,
            "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
            "Parameters": {
            "FunctionName": "arn:xxxxx",
            "Payload": {
                "payload.$": "$",
                "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
            }
            }
        },
        "metadata-step": {
            "Next": "Map state",
            "Retry": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                "Lambda.ServiceException",
                "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
            }
            ],
            "Catch": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
                ],
                "Next": "post-process"
            }
            ],
            "Type": "Task",
            "TimeoutSeconds": 86400,
            "OutputPath": "$",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
            "Parameters": {
            "FunctionName": "arn:xxxxx",
            "Payload": {
                "payload.$": "$",
                "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token",
                "File_List": "$.File_List"
            }
            }
        },
        "Map state": {
            "Type": "Map",
            "ResultPath": "$.Single.File",
            "Next": "check-file-processing-status",
            "Catch": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
                ],
                "Next": "check-file-processing-status"
            }
            ],
            "Iterator": {
            "StartAt": "fetch-sample-data-step",
            "States": {
                "fetch-sample-data-step": {
                "End": true,
                "Retry": [
                    {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "Lambda.ServiceException",
                        "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                        "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                    "MaxAttempts": 6,
                    "BackoffRate": 2
                    }
                ],
                "Type": "Task",
                "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
                "Parameters": {
                    "FunctionName": "arn:xxxxx",
                    "Payload": {
                    "payload.$": "$",
                    "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                    "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            },
            "ItemsPath": "$.Payload.File_List",
            "MaxConcurrency": 20
        },
        "check-file-processing-status": {
            "Next": "post-process",
            "Retry": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                "Lambda.ServiceException",
                "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
            }
            ],
            "Type": "Task",
            "TimeoutSeconds": 86400,
            "OutputPath": "$",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
            "Parameters": {
            "FunctionName": "arn:xxxxx",
            "Payload": {
                "payload.$": "$",
                "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
            }
            }
        },
        "post-process": {
            "End": true,
            "Retry": [
            {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                "Lambda.ServiceException",
                "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
            }
            ],
            "Type": "Task",
            "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "FunctionName": "arn:xxxxx",
                "Payload": {
                    "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                    "payload.$": "$"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so in this my map function lambda is fetch-sample-data-step . In Lambda configuration I have set Unreserved account concurrency to 1906 . And sometimes it successfully complete sometimes around 109th transaction it is giving error.

and my function fetch-sample-data-step which is creating issue   is made by python cdk like this which is DockerImageFunction:

```py
sample_data_v1= _lambda.DockerImageFunction(
    self, "sample_data_v1",
    code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset("./catalog/src/code"),
    memory_size=8046,
    function_name="fetch_sample_data",
    timeout=core.Duration.minutes(15),
    )
```

Comment: are you calling the Lambda ARN with the Version Alias? I remember seeing something about provisioned concurrency working with that. If you do not provide anything, Lambda chooses $LATEST which doesn't have the concurrency configuration

Comment: @diegosantiviago thanks for reply. Not sure about this. How I can add Version Alias in this json or python cdk code ? and what is indication that it is added via Version Alias  or not ? Currently I checked there is no Alias with my lambda

Comment: You need to use the ARN with the Alias that you created. There's some information here:

https://repost.aws/questions/QUHUTSmYGtQLGC3_ZE2VbGXA/lambda-provisioned-concurrency-for-latest-or-updating-api-gateway-to-refer-to-version#AN9Hv_GiE2QWi8athQBM7VIg